# Im new to c and dont understand why this program works the first time i run it but the second time it breaks

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    while(1 == 1){
        int a;
        int b;
        scanf("%d", &a);
        scanf("%d", &b);
        if(a > b){
            printf("A is bigger than B\n");
        }
        else if(a == b){
          printf("A and B are equal\n");
        }
        else{
          printf("B is bigger than A\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Everything worked as expected but i ran the program again and it broke, im not sure why but it kept printing the last message over and over again

Comment: When you write "ran it again", did you stop it and start again or are you talking about second iteration of the loop? What did you input, btw?

Comment: You probably typed something other than a valid integer.  `scanf` doesn't deal so well with that.

Comment: Not checking the return value of [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) is a sure-fire way of invoking [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Comment: Instead of `scanf("%d", &a);`, it's better to do something like `if(scanf("%d", &a) != 1) { printf("input error!\n"); exit(1); }`.

Comment: Not your problem, but: using `while(1 == 1)` is kinda... silly.  Whoever taught you to do it that way is an odd duck, at best.

Comment: In your first time running the program, I'm sure you tested with integers, but in your second time, I'm almost also 99% sure you tested with other kinds of inputs such as floating-points. They are not the same because `scanf` expects only a certain format.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are inputting floating-point numbers but your `scanf` only accepts integers.

Change

```
int a; // -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
int b;
scanf("%d", &a);
scanf("%d", &b);
```

To

```
float a; // -1.0, -0.5, 0.0, -0.5, 1.0, 2.0, ...
float b;
scanf("%f", &a);
scanf("%f", &b);
```

Comment: Where did you get that information about input? The OP did not respond to requests for clarification.

Comment: @Gerhardh The OP is obviouesly a beginner. They think inputting `1` is the same as `1.0` and in their mind, it doesn't make a difference. But just because they didn't tell us the inputs doesn't mean we cannot make assumptions. It is a common mistake for newbies.

Answer (score 0):

The function scanf() returns the number of elements it has processed, you should check it.

```
if (scanf("%d", &a) != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid input.”);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

You provided the format specifier %d to scanf, which expects an integer argument. So you can't use floating point numbers.

For more information about scanf, type man scanf on your linux terminal. Or you can visit the cpp.reference site.

I'd refrain from commenting on the condition for the while loop, as the comments already do.